# When I should use Ongoing and when I should use in progress?

Tags: grammar

If I wanted to say the meeting is still haven’t finished yet

“The meeting is still ongoing”
“The meeting is still in progress”

Which one will be more appropriate and why?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to understand the difference between *ongoing* and *still ongoing*.  *Still ongoing* is only used when you have referred to something being ongoing before.

Example:

> Monday: "Our move to the new place is ongoing."
>
> Tuesday: "Our move
> to the new place is **still** ongoing."
>
> Wednesday: "Our move to the new place is done."

Example from [Yahoo](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090318164227AA4jj65&guccounter=2)

*Still* is used to let the reader know that the situation is the same as before; it is intensifying 'ongoing'.

So assuming you mean just 'ongoing', *in progress* is better.

> *The meeting is still in progress.*

This is because 'ongoing' refers to when something isn't finished and will continue for some time.

*In progress* refers to when a task is underway and will finish in the near future.

So unless it is a lengthy, important meeting, *in progress* is better.

**Some evidence to back this up:**

https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/577232

Comment: Why the downvote?  I'm happy to make changes and edit.

Comment: You took your quote without attribution from Yahoo answers. You need to fix that first of all. https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090318164227AA4jj65&guccounter=1

Comment: I'm with you on still. But ongoing, underway, in progress, are pretty much synonymous to me.

Comment: I catch your drift.  'Underway' I did use as a synonym.  But the (small) difference between *ongoing* and *in progress* is that if you were talking about a longer event (days, weeks, months) you'd use *ongoing*.